# Cycles volume render failure

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I am trying to render a very straight forward scene in cycles with some volume. I have tried creating a large cube with volume, and I have also added volume to the World. Everything looks great in the preview, and in the render right up to the last noise pass, then poof, the volume disappears. I'm mystified.[image]

Comment: Are you using denoising?

Comment: Yes - but I have turned it off (both NLM and D-Noise) and on with the same result.